# Does relativistic glider violate principle of equivalence?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, relativity, inertial-frames, equivalence-principle

[The relativistic glider](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0612131) proposed can slow down the fall of an object in gravitational field. Will this violate the principle of equivalence which says that one cannot distinguish between free falling and inertial motion? Suppose an observer in a box while free falling. When he switches on the device which deforms periodically as described in the research paper, what would he observe?

Comment: It's important to note that the principle of equivalence is a local statement. A _very small_ observer cannot distinguish between free falling and inertial motion. This paper talks about extended bodies.